# Keep external hard disk running regardless of inactivity

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive

After being inactive for about an hour, my Seagate 3TB hard disk becomes inaccessible to programs (such as Deluge).
The moment any file/directory related tasks are initiated nautilus prompts me with a window showing the contents of that drive, but other programs depending on the storage space have been interrupted beforehand when the drive was considered inactive.
**Is there any way to keep the hard disk running regardless of user activity?**

Additional information:
File system: `ext4`
Operating system: `linux 3.13`

Comment: If all else fails, you can do a cronjob every 59 minutes that copies a file of minimum size on your hard disk, thus creating disk activity.

Comment: I'll probably try that.

Answer (score 2):

hdparm -S0 /dev/sdX

from man:

```
-S     Put the drive into idle (low-power) mode, and also set the standby (spindown) timeout for  the  drive.   This  timeout
          value  is used by the drive to determine how long to wait (with no disk activity) before turning off the spindle motor
          to save power.  Under such circumstances, the drive may take as long as 30 seconds to respond  to  a  subsequent  disk
          access, though most drives are much quicker.  The encoding of the timeout value is somewhat peculiar.  A value of zero
          means "timeouts are disabled": the device will not automatically enter standby mode.  Values from  1  to  240  specify
          multiples  of  5 seconds, yielding timeouts from 5 seconds to 20 minutes.  Values from 241 to 251 specify from 1 to 11
          units of 30 minutes, yielding timeouts from 30 minutes to 5.5 hours.  A value of 252 signifies a timeout  of  21  min‐
          utes.  A value of 253 sets a vendor-defined timeout period between 8 and 12 hours, and the value 254 is reserved.  255
          is interpreted as 21 minutes plus 15 seconds.  Note that some older drives may have very different interpretations  of
          these values.
```